# Improve loading speed of a dynatree (300 nodes) which takes 20 to 25 seconds

Tags: performance, dynatree

I am building the entire JSON reading contents of each node and its details from the database. Then use initAjax method to load the dynatree. It takes about 20 to 25 seconds to load.Is there any way to speed up the loading time. I understand I could use lazy loading instead but I need the search ability on the tree for which I am assuming I need all the node present and not load when they are activated. The tree is going to grow considerbly more in the future months and years. Please suggest/advise what is the best path to take in my scenario. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could use lazy loading and do searching in the backend:
Send the search query via Ajax, and let the server return the matching nodes (with parents, if neccessary).
Then use the Dynatree API to add or highlight the matches.

This wouldn't help if you do a serch '*', but should be considerably faster in the common case.